# cakephp saveall is saving with multiple query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have an array that is saved into the database using saveall in cakephp. recently i noticed that the array has around 100 set of values and 100 insert queries are run to save this. This is done as a transaction and then later commiting it. Each query takes around 1ms. so 100 queries add up a lot of time. I am sure that there is some ways to do this in one query.

i tried

```
$this->User->savemany($data)
```

but there is no change.

is there any other method by which i could save something like this

```
INSERT INTO users (ID, Value)
```

VALUES (1, 'First'), (2, 'Second'), (3, 'Third');

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a way to accomplish this without getting into custom SQL or extending AppModel so that it had a method to run optimized `INSERT` statements in certain situations. **

Keep in mind that you won't always be saving a model's data all by itself. Sometimes you're saving related objects.

For example: `Person hasMany Car`. When you save multiple `Person`s, each with an arbitrary number of `Car`(s), CakePHP needs to get back the ID for each Person record saved before it can associate their Car records in the database.

Like I said, you could extend AppModel and either augment the saveAll method to inspect the structure of the data that's being saved and have it hook off into a custom method that you write to do what you want, but it's probably going to add more to the saveAll method overhead than it's worth.

** The best optimization you can do without a lot of custom coding would be wrapping the saveAll with a transaction so you don't init and commit for each of them. Example:

```
$this->Model->begin();
$this->Model->saveAll(data);
$this->Model->commit();
```

Comment: Also, I wouldn't worry if we're really just talking 100 records. If you were talking about thousands of `INSERT`s happening pretty frequently, then yeah, maybe think about optimizing.

Comment: even i was not worried about this.. but things stated to get worse because i am running this on a shared hosting and i  am getting some traffic to the site.. But dont you think its wired that cakephp does not have a method to do this ..

Comment: Are you positive that your bottleneck is the INSERT statements? What have you used to monitor database performance? Also, it's not too weird. Rails doesn't do it either. But you COULD wrap the inserts in a transaction to commit them all at once. I'll see if I can find some code to do so.

Comment: ehhh, so could you give me some dap if your question is answered? trying to build up rep here :) thanks.

Comment: I read about saveAll method params and in description it is written that in the options (params for saveall . atomic is the one key which we are passing in to options key ) "`atomic`: If true (default), will attempt to save all records in a single transaction."   I tried using that also and I it is also executing many insert queries.